# Reading text file as a floating number in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, file-io

I have a text file with a single floating number in it that needs to be opened and read as a floating value so I can use it in my equations. I have successfully read in the text file as a string and checked it in UITextView to make sure the file was in the correct path etc. Below is how I am reading the file and I have tried using an NSScanner to read the number as a float but cannot get it to work.

```
NSString *filePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"time" ofType: @"txt"];
NSString *textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
// i know the above won't work because it reads the file as a string
```

Comment: `[textFromFile floatValue]`

Comment: wow it is really that easy. Thank you @BryanChen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
[textFromFile doubleValue];
```